# Smooth horizontal scrolling using transform translate. Everything works, but because of the bug there are prolags. native js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a smooth horizontal scroll for my page by changing transform(translate);. Everything works fine, but if I don't wait for the scroll animation to finish and just start scrolling further forward or backward, then the scroll animation happens abruptly. I would be very grateful if someone would help to get rid of this bug. Here is the code I use:

https://codepen.io/bogdandranicin/pen/LYMvPZY

```js
function mainTitleScroll() {
  const mainContainer = document.getElementById('main-container');
  const descriptionContainer = document.getElementById('description-container');

  let mlMain = 0;
  let mlDesc = 0;

  let speedMain = 100;
  let speedDesc = 200;

  let scroll = true; // Добавьте эту переменную, чтобы контролировать возможность скролла

  window.addEventListener('wheel', function (e) {
    if (scroll) {
      if (e.deltaY >= 0) {
        // 'scroll down'
        mlMain += speedMain;
        mlDesc += speedDesc;

        if (mlMain > mainContainer.offsetWidth - window.innerWidth) {
          mlMain = mainContainer.offsetWidth - window.innerWidth;
        }
        if (mlDesc > descriptionContainer.offsetWidth - window.innerWidth) {
          mlDesc = descriptionContainer.offsetWidth - window.innerWidth;
        }

        mainContainer.style.transform = `translate(-${mlMain}px,0)`;
        descriptionContainer.style.transform = `translate(-${mlDesc}px,0)`;
      }
      if (e.deltaY <= 0) {
        // 'scroll up'
        mlMain -= speedMain;
        mlDesc -= speedDesc;

        if (mlMain < 0) {
          mlMain = 0;
        }
        if (mlDesc < 0) {
          mlDesc = 0;
        }

        mainContainer.style.transform = `translate(-${mlMain}px,0)`;
        descriptionContainer.style.transform = `translate(-${mlDesc}px,0)`;
      }
    }
  });

  // Добавьте обработчики событий для сенсорного ввода (touch)
  let startX, startY;

  window.addEventListener('touchstart', function (event) {
    startX = event.touches[0].clientX;
    startY = event.touches[0].clientY;
  });

  window.addEventListener('touchend', function (event) {
    var endX = event.changedTouches[0].clientX;
    var endY = event.changedTouches[0].clientY;

    var diffX = startX - endX;
    var diffY = startY - endY;

    if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
      if (scroll) {
        if (diffX > 0) {
          // Свайп влево
          swipeLeft();
        } else {
          // Свайп вправо
          swipeRight();
        }
      }
    }
  });

  function swipeLeft() {
    mlMain += speedMain;
    mlDesc += speedDesc;

    if (mlMain > mainContainer.offsetWidth - window.innerWidth) {
      mlMain = mainContainer.offsetWidth - window.innerWidth;
    }
    if (mlDesc > descriptionContainer.offsetWidth - window.innerWidth) {
      mlDesc = descriptionContainer.offsetWidth - window.innerWidth;
    }

    mainContainer.style.transform = `translate(-${mlMain}px,0)`;
    descriptionContainer.style.transform = `translate(-${mlDesc}px,0)`;
  }

  function swipeRight() {
    mlMain -= speedMain;
    mlDesc -= speedDesc;

    if (mlMain < 0) {
      mlMain = 0;
    }
    if (mlDesc < 0) {
      mlDesc = 0;
    }

    mainContainer.style.transform = `translate(-${mlMain}px,0)`;
    descriptionContainer.style.transform = `translate(-${mlDesc}px,0)`;
  }
}
```

I've tried using scrolltop, scrollLeft, scrollBy, or changing the animation function, but unfortunately nothing helps.

In fact, I would like to repeat the functionality of locomotive scroll, since using it I cannot achieve a result in which two containers will scroll under each other at different speeds without bugs.